# Testing Cypher statements in PyCharm using the Graph Database Console

Tags: neo4j, pycharm, cypher

Every time I try to run the Cypher code in PyCharm using the Graph Database Console I get this error:

```
can't find '__main__' module in '

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How do I execute Cypher statements to test them?

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in PyCharm and the solution was to provide the full path to the script (including full file name) in the 'Script path' under 'Run / Debug configurations'